# Symfony 3.3.3 - default controller and container

Tags: php, symfony

I downloaded last stable version of Symfony (3.3.3) and on start I have error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getParameter" of class "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController".
```

This is:

```
'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
```

Before 3.3.3 version Symfony controllers extended

> Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php

Now extends:

> Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController\AbstractController.php

So... How can I get data from container? In documentation (3.3 and 4.0 versions) Controller extends Controller, not AbstractController.

If I change AbstractController to Controller application works well, but do I should this change?

Comment: It depends.  The AbstractController only provides access to certain basic services.  There is no general access to the container.  The idea is that you define your controller as a service and then inject whatever additional services/parameters you need.  Check for autowire in the manual.  It is a big change really targeted for Symfony 4.  You can continue to use the "original" base controller class and things should work pretty much as before.  Also instructive to look at the FrameworkBundle/Controller code.

Comment: I have the same problem. Same problem with the security module don't work. I return to the version 3.2.x

Comment: I have the same problem with a freshly generated project. It's already broken directly after running composer create-project.

Answer (score 2):

They have already [reverted the change](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/commit/c4c2ef5d383fd0a39adbb1eb5c8840a412fd4335) on the symfony standard edition so I would say that going back to `Controller` instead of `AbstractController` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Today came the version 3.3.4 that fixes this and other problems. 
Here's the news: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-3-4-released
To correct the error you must update with `composer`

```
composer update
```

Answer (score -2):

You may create project with working version with this command:
    `php symfony new project_name 3.3.2`
Current version is broken now.