# Symfony AbstractController Not Found After Composer Update

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I just ran a composer update and now when I try to access my website I get this error:

> ClassNotFoundException in SecurityController.php line 28: Attempted to
>   load class "AbstractController" from namespace
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller". Did you forget a "use"
>   statement for another namespace?

When I go into vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Controller/SecurityController.php even PHPStorm is now telling me "Undefined class AbstractController"...

What happened to "AbstractController" and how do I get my application to work again? I've searched online and found one person who had the same issue, but there's not fix.  https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2678

Comment: Hi, try to execute again compose update and then rm -Rf var/cache/*/

Comment: I've done that as well as clearing the cache bin/console cache:clear, and also removing the entire vendor dir and doing a composer install... Everything I get this same error.

Comment: Version of symfony?

Comment: Sorry, it is version 3.2

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904806/symfony-3-3-3-default-controller-and-container   and try to change AbstractController to Controller

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#minimum-stability try to execute composer update with minimum-stability

Comment: I changed use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController; to use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; in all of the fos files. Looks like I am in need of a upgrade to 3.4 or 4.0

Comment: Yep.  AbstractController was introduced in 3.3.  Bit of a mystery how composer managed to install a FOSUserBundle which requires 3.3 or later when you have 3.2.  But maybe you are using the master branch of FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Here's what I am using: "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",

Comment: Using a dev branch is always a bit dangerous since you never know when stuff might be added that is not yet ready for release.  Might be better to use a stable branch.  According to github, only the master branch uses the AbstractController.  The latest stable tag, 2.0.2 looks fine. https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2683

Comment: Good call. I removed that @dev, removed my vendor directory, and then re-ran the composer update - everything seems to be back in working order now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solve it setting in composer.json the following line on require:  "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0", after that I have done a composer update and that worked.